# After Effects - Unable to track motion accurately for screen recording when scrolling occurs

Tags: after-effects, screen-casting, tracking, motion

I'm attempting to create a simple help video where I demonstrate the use of an online application, so I'm using a screen recording as my source video. I've created a shape layer that will serve as box to highlight a certain part of the webpage I want to draw attention to. In this scene, the page scrolls down. At this point I would like the highlight-box to scroll with the page. I've attempted to use the Track Motion tool to target the highlight-box to features on the page. However, the tracker is doing a horrible job of tracking items when the page scrolls. I've attempted to position the motion tracker on to many of the page's items, but it's just not able to get a handle on anything effectively.

I've read through a few different tutorials and watched a couple of videos too, and so I don't think that there is a problem with my work flow.

Is anybody able to tell me why I am having such trouble tracking this scroll motion? Does anybody have any recommendations for solving this problem?

I've attached a link to the aep file at [Highlights-3.aep](http://www.webfinesse.co.nz/Downloads/Highlights-3.aep)  (182KB), and the relevant clip file at [video clip](http://www.webfinesse.co.nz/Downloads/FindFullText-CCDHB-Scene03.mp4) (1,635 KB). Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The File you uploaded is only the project file - you will need to upload the clip aswell. I assume that the nature of screens when filmed make tracking a nightmare. Have you tried manually keyframing the y-position? If the motion isn't too complex, this should bring better results faster.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but I would do this within the screen recording software itself. Something like ScreenFlow has lots of options for highlighting and calling out cursors etc. You'll find it a lot easier than trying to track screens in AE.

Comment: @FlorianClaaßen Yes, I think it could be because of the screen recording; AE just can't find anything to hold on to. Keyframing the highlight-box might be something I will end up resorting to.